# Wind on a Terraformed Titan?

Tags: weather, terraforming, wind

My story is set on a future fully-terraformed Titan that's covered by a global ocean, heated to a comfortable temperature, and given an artificial atmosphere that mimics earth's. With that said, I've read that on the surface Titan's winds aren't very strong at all. Like maybe there's a constant gentle breeze. But going upwards the winds become incredibly powerful. I'm trying to allow my characters to fly around (instead of walking) because of the low gravity and wind, so that's all I'm trying to find out: the wind situation and how it changes going upwards into the sky. I'm assuming there must be layers of wind intensity stratified through the atmosphere, I'm just not sure what that might be like under the conditions of the terraforming.

Comment: What do you mean with 'the stratification of layers of wind intensity' being influenced by terraforming? And what exactly is your question (or: what do you mean by "the wind situation" :)?

Comment: Are you _sure_ the winds become incredibly powerful? Have a think about the atmospheric density at the altitude of those fast winds. Hint: its pretty tenuous.

Comment: Lol, no I'm not sure at all, so I'm trying to understand it better. What I've read refers obviously to the actual moon as it is today (per our current understanding) which is that it has tame wind at the surface but more forceful winds higher up. I'm just trying to understand if it's ridiculous to say in my story that on the surface there's a light breeze of the new, terraformed Titan with strong winds higher up in the sky. Fiction is fiction but I'm just trying to find at least a little scientific reasoning, even if incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

Terraforming Titan will have a significant impact on wind speed. Currently, the sunlight which reaches Titan is almost all absorbed by the atmosphere before reaching the surface. It also has a thicker atmosphere than Earth’s. A denser atmosphere takes more energy to move. The lack of sunlight reaching the surface limits wind generation from surface evaporation. Upper atmosphere winds are fast due to the lack of atmospheric mass. It is not unlike the wind on Mars. It rushes around the planet at hurricane speeds, but the air is so thin it has little impact.

Decreasing the thickness of Titan’s atmosphere would increase its speed but reduce its carrying capacity. Removing the hydrocarbon smog and replacing it with oxygen would allow sunlight (natural and artificial) to reach the surface. Perhaps you keep the thicker atmosphere but remove the light blocking smog. It will still take more energy to generate winds than with thinner air, but the light will hit the surface and cause updrafts.

I do not know of any method for accurately calculating the wind speed of a planet. Even with an accurate calculator, it would need the exact atmospheric composition, the amount of light hitting, rotational speed, gravity interactions with orbiting parent, humidity, albedo, and surface features. It might be better to guestimate. It is unlikely the average person would fly high enough to need to deal with the thin high-speed upper atmospheric winds.

I would recommend simply using a fraction (i.e., 1/3, ¼, 1/10.) of Earth’s average variable wind speed for Titan and remember that the force of wind in a thicker atmosphere will be greater than wind of the same speed on Earth. It will feel like the wind is blowing harder than expected based on its speed. Consider seasonality, storm surges, and other variables when telling your story. Also, it will take more energy to fly into the wind than to go with it. It might prove to be difficult to fly home if your house is upwind from your location. The weather somewhat depends on how you want it to impact your story. A few lines about how the weather was tailored to be mild will result in calm skies and easy muscle-powered flight. If you want people to struggle, you can have someone complain about how they wish terraforming did a better job taming the weather and show people struggling with flying from time to time. You could even have people (adrenaline junkies) who try and reach the higher altitude jet streams to rapidly transit across the planet. Best wishes and good writing!